# Access 2003: count(*) produces syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using ms-access and for some reason, the code here produces a Syntax error which I dont understand.

```
UPDATE Korrekturentlastung
SET Schueler = SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Korrekturentlastung 
    WHERE 
        Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Kuerzel = Korrekturentlastung.Kuerzel
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Klasse = Korrekturentlastung.Klasse
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Fach = Korrekturentlastung.Fach
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Kursart = Korrekturentlastung.Kursart
```

The error is:

```
Syntax error. in query expression 'SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Korrekturentlastung'
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst @Gordon Linoff has correctly identified the syntax error in your query, if you were to run the query in MS Access, you'll likely receive the familiar response:

> Operation must use an updateable query.

This arises as a result of a restriction of the JET database engined used by MS Access whereby no part of an `update` query can use aggregation. In your case, this arises as a result of the use of `count(*)`.

One possible alternative is to use the [`DCount`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3) domain aggregate function, which is evaluated separately from the evaluation of the main query and therefore retains the *"updateability"* of the query.

```
update korrekturentlastung
set schueler = 
dcount
(
    "*",
    "Korrekturentlastung",
    "Kuerzel = " & Korrekturentlastung.Kuerzel & " and "
    "Klasse = " & Korrekturentlastung.Klasse & " and " 
    "Fach = " & Korrekturentlastung.Fach & " and "
    "Kursart = " & Korrekturentlastung.Kursart
)
```

Note that if your fields are text fields, you'll also need to surround the above values with single or double quotes, e.g.:

```
update korrekturentlastung
set schueler = 
dcount
(
    "*",
    "Korrekturentlastung",
    "Kuerzel = '" & Korrekturentlastung.Kuerzel & "' and "
    "Klasse = '" & Korrekturentlastung.Klasse & "' and " 
    "Fach = '" & Korrekturentlastung.Fach & "' and "
    "Kursart = '" & Korrekturentlastung.Kursart & "'"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries need their own parentheses:

```
UPDATE Korrekturentlastung
SET Schueler = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM Korrekturentlastung 
                WHERE Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Kuerzel = Korrekturentlastung.Kuerzel
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Klasse = Korrekturentlastung.Klasse
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Fach = Korrekturentlastung.Fach
AND Korrekturentlastung_Kurs.Kursart = Korrekturentlastung.Kursart
              );
```